# Can't receive RTSP live stream from an IP cam

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, rtsp

I want to receive live streaming from an IP camera using RTSP, I'm getting **'Can't play this video'**, and the following Exception:

```
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411): setDataSource IOException happend : 
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: rtsp://192.168.30.108:554
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1052)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:907)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:834)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:973)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:337)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:247)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:237)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at com.example.video_rtsp.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:59)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 14:06:26.945: D/MediaPlayer(19411): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
07-16 14:06:26.955: V/MediaPlayer(19411): setVideoSurfaceTexture
07-16 14:06:26.955: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(19411): setAudioStreamType: 3
07-16 14:06:26.955: V/MediaPlayer(19411): MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
07-16 14:06:26.955: V/MediaPlayer(19411): setVideoSurfaceTexture
07-16 14:06:26.955: V/MediaPlayer(19411): prepareAsync
07-16 14:06:26.965: D/ProgressBar(19411): setProgressDrawable drawableHeight = 48
07-16 14:06:26.985: D/AbsSeekBar(19411): AbsSeekBar Constructor: misSeebarAnimationAvailable = true
```

I'm using the following way:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) ((Activity) ctx).findViewById(R.id.videoView);

//add controls to a MediaPlayer like play, pause.
MediaController mc = new MediaController(ctx);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);

//Set the path of Video or URI
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.30.108:554"));

//Set the focus
videoView.requestFocus();
```

**can't say I'm sure this is the problem, but I think it's because this camera software needs authentication, but if so, I don't know how to provide the authentication to it.**

---

After using MediaPlayer with setDataSource, I'm getting the following Exception:

```
07-21 12:04:11.677: W/System.err(17714): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
07-21 12:04:11.677: W/System.err(17714):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
```

I'm not sure if that related to a wrong way in setting the headers or not :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("rtsp://192.168.30.108:554");
Map<String , String> headres = new HashMap<String, String>();
headres.put("Authorization", "Basic ce0ca0f0864513c28c7be98f0f929be7b1f5db79"); //Also tried it without "Basic"
headres.put("encryption", "Default");
headres.put("mac", "9002A9D89200");
headres.put("random", "1715377261");
headres.put("realm", "Login to 90:02:a9:d8:92:00");

mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri, headres);
```

and this is a screenshots of login process headers and json data using firebug:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried basic authentication `rtsp://username:password@192.168.30.108:554`? You may need a stream name too `rtsp://username:password@192.168.30.108:554/stream_name`

Comment: @aergistal yea I tried it and nothing new

Comment: Try to play the stream on the same machine using another player like VLC

Comment: @aergistal I tried that on VLC, and once I pressed play it popped up a dialog for user and password and once I entered them the stream played without problems

Comment: Did you try to put the authentication into the URI (in VLC as well) like @aergistal mentioned in his first comment?
In your example using `rtsp://username:password@192.168.30.108:554` instead of `rtsp://192.168.30.108:554`

Comment: @Levit putting authentication into the URI of (VLC) works efficiently.

Comment: I'm not sure about that base64 encoding. How did you obtain it?

Comment: I don't know how, I didn't obtain it, I captured it when the login process completed successfully in the web service of the camera

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat: Have you found a solution? I got the same exception when trying to connect to a DLink IP Camera.

Comment: @Christopher unfortunately no

Answer (score 1):

If the authentication mechanism is **HTTP basic authentication** then there might be way to set the required HTTP header: the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E%29) class has a method `setDataSource` taking a `Map` parameter for headers:

`public void setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri, Map<String, String> headers)`

You must set the [Authorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) header:

`Authorization: Basic _credentials_`

`_credentials_` is the RFC2045-MIME Base64 encoding of the `username:password` string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, kindly have a look at my updates

Comment: also when I performed decoding it gives me a binary data file not a specific words combination, and when encoding the username:password manually it doesn't give me the above code